# how to save the result of the function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function where I get the MAC of the pc and I want to save that MAC in the database, but it doesn't save me and I don't know why ..

I use this function in another function where I update the mac field, but the result of the function does not let me save it to the database.

```
public function update(Request $request, $url)
{
      $users = User::where('url', $url)->get();
      foreach ($users as $user) {
            if(!empty($user->mac)){
                 if($user->mac == self::mac()){
                     return redirect()->route('login', ['url' => $user->url]);
                 }else{
                     return redirect('error_ip');
                 }
           }else{
                $user->mac = $this->mac(); //18-C5-3D-45-EE-03
                $user->save(); //the field in the database is in string.
                              //I don't update the mac field in the database
           }
       }
}

public function mac(){
     $mac='UNKNOWN';
     foreach(explode("\n",str_replace(' ','',trim(`getmac`,"\n"))) as $i)
     if(strpos($i,'Tcpip')>-1){$mac=substr($i,0,17);break;}
   echo $mac;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you should return it in mac function

remove this part of the function:

```
echo $mac;
```

and replace it with:

```
return $mac;
```

and try again